# What is wrong with the formula in my code?

Tags: java

We've been set a task to calculate user input. My code compiles, however when I test it my output for the refund is always 0 :(
Users are meant to enter their distance and self contribution when prompted, but what exactly is wrong with my formula for refund? Can anybody shed some light on this for me?

```
 import java.util.*;
 public final class UserCalc {`
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in );`
         System.out.print("Please enter the distance ");
         int distance = scanner.nextInt();
         System.out.print("Please enter the percentage of self contribution ");
         int selfcon = scanner.nextInt();
         int trainprice = (75 + (2 / 10)) * distance;
         int carprice = (26 + (7 / 10)) * distance;

         int refund = (Math.min(trainprice, carprice)) * ((100 - selfcon) / 100);

         System.out.print("You get a refund of " + refund + " pounds");
         int age = scanner.nextInt();
     }
 }
```

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT AT US

Comment: use double and not ints (2.0/10.0 and not 2/10 which is 0)

Answer (score 0):

Because  result of `((100 - selfcon)/100)` is always zero and you works with `integers` you should use `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using integer arithmetic rather than floating point arithmetic, so expressions like 2/10 evaluate to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
double distance = scanner.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Please enter the percentage of self contribution ");
double selfcon = scanner.nextDouble();
double trainprice = (75 + (2 / 10)) * distance;
double carprice = (26 + (7 / 10)) * distance;

doulbe refund = (Math.min(trainprice, carprice)) * ((100 - selfcon) / 100);

System.out.print("You get a refund of " + refund + " pounds");
int age = scanner.nextInt();
```